# Spin a slot machine in specific range (max range)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm newbie and try to imitate this slot machine work, example 1: https://github.com/momokang/slotmachine

Before starting to spin, I set the max value of the slot machine (ex: 500) and then I press Spin button. The result was less or maybe equal the max value (029, 358, 500); but not more than 500 (ex: 506, 789, etc...)

Is it possible to do this?

Here's the source code: https://jsfiddle.net/c07gk6yq/

Html file:

```
<div class="container">

            <div class="slotwrapper" id="example1">
                <ul id = "ul1">
                    <li value=0>0</li>
                    <li value=1>1</li>
                    <li value=2>2</li>
                    <li value=3>3</li>
                    <li value=4>4</li>
                    <li value=5>5</li>
                    <li value=6>6</li>
                    <li value=7>7</li>
                    <li value=8>8</li>
                    <li value=9 class="text-danger">9</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id = "ul2">
                    <li value=0>0</li>
                    <li value=1>1</li>
                    <li value=2>2</li>
                    <li value=3>3</li>
                    <li value=4>4</li>
                    <li value=5>5</li>
                    <li value=6>6</li>
                    <li value=7>7</li>
                    <li value=8>8</li>
                    <li value=9 class="text-danger">9</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id ="ul3">
                    <li value=0>0</li>
                    <li value=1>1</li>
                    <li value=2>2</li>
                    <li value=3>3</li>
                    <li value=4>4</li>
                    <li value=5>5</li>
                    <li value=6>6</li>
                    <li value=7>7</li>
                    <li value=8>8</li>
                    <li value=9 class="text-danger">9</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="btn-example1">Spin</button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapse-example1">
                <div class="well">
                    <code>
                        $('#btn-example1').click(function() {<br/>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;$('#example1 ul').playSpin();<br/>
                        });
                    </code>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slotmachine.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn-example1').click(function() {
        $('#example1 ul').playSpin();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#ul1 li:first").text()==$(this).text(){
           alert("first");            
        };
        $("#ul1 li:last").text()==$(this).text(){
           alert("last");            
        };
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range/1527834) help?

Comment: Thank you Rob. I've read this and i think it's could be useful. I wonder how to get min, max from li list?

Comment: New things for me but I'll try. Thank you.